# Accepting only alphanumerics in Golang and ncurses

Tags: go, ncurses

So, I'm teaching myself some Golang by making a simple resource management game with ncurses. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/rthornton128/goncurses) to connect Golang to ncurses.

I've made a simple text input panel that takes in one character at a time, displays it, and then adds it to a string composing the user's response. Here's what it looks like:

```
// Accept characters, printing them until end
ch := window.GetChar()
kstr := gc.KeyString(ch)
response := ""
cur := 0
for kstr != "enter" {
    // Diagnostic print to get key code of current character 
    window.Move(0,0)
    window.ClearToEOL()
    window.MovePrint(0, 0, ch)

    // If its a backspace or delete, remove a character
    // Otherwise as long as its a regular character add it
    if ((ch == 127 || ch == 8) && cur != 0){
        cur--
        response = response[:len(response)-1] 
        window.MovePrint(y, (x + cur), " ")
    } else if (ch >= 33 && ch <= 122  && cur <= 52) {
        window.MovePrint(y, (x + cur), kstr)
        response = response + kstr
        cur++
    }

    // Get next character
    ch = window.GetChar()
    kstr = gc.KeyString(ch)
}
```

However, the arrow and function keys seem to be coming up as keycodes already associated with the normal a-zA-Z characters. For example, right-arrow comes up as 67 and F1 as 80. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here, or if there's a better approach to taking in alphanumerics through ncurses? I'd like to avoid ncurses fields and classes as much as possible, because the point here is to learn Golang, not ncurses. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not enable the *keypad* mode, (n)curses will return the individual bytes which make up a special key.

To fix, add this to your program's initialization:

```
stdscr.Keypad(true)   // allow keypad input
```

which will return special keys such as right-arrow as values above 255.  goncurses has symbols defined for those, e.g., `KEY_RIGHT`.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly it. Thanks so much!